# Matlab, intersection of two vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

i want to determinate the positions when 2 vectors are intersected without using repetitive operations. For example

```
A = [ 2 2 3 4 5]
B = [ 2 3 3 8 5]
```

And the output will be

```
R = [1 3 5].
```

Comment: Or you can use `R = intersect(A,B)`

Comment: @GameOfThrows this returns the data common to both A and B with no repetitions. Here: `2 3 5`

Comment: You could use `[C,ia,ib] = intersect(A,B)` which will give you the position in `A` and `B` using `ia`and `ib`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) with a logical matrix:

```
A = [2 2 3 4 5];
B = [2 3 3 8 5];

R = find(A == B)

    1   3   5
```

The expression `A == B` will create a logical matrix where an element is `true` (1) if the element in `A` is equal to the element in `B` and `false` (0) if they are not equal. Then `find` will identify the positions in this logical matrix where the values are `true`.